# update part of JSON using capture function in jq

Tags: jq

Say that I have JSON, which contains missing data, which can be calculated from data already present using regex.

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "a100",
    "data": [
      {
        "something": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a101",
    "data": [
      {
        "something": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "b100",
    "data": [
      {
        "something": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Assumption: for simplicity/brewity of this example I'm using array as top-level element. Imagine wildly bigger JSON with bigger nesting of data residing in this array, ie. it cannot be solved by adding array creation.

Say, that we need to calculate `something` from `id`, where `something` should be `id` with its first two chars added to the end:

```
[
  {
    "id": "a100",
    "data": [
      {
        "something": "a100a1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a101",
    "data": [
      {
        "something": "a101a1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "b100",
    "data": [
      {
        "something": "b100b1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I was able to come up with:

```
jq '.[] 
| . as $env 
| .data[].something=($env.id | capture("(?<cid>[a-z0-9]{2})(?<rest>.*)") | .cid+.rest+.cid)' < test.json
```

but this "solution" omits everything up from the declared variable, which in this simplified example is top-level array. So the question: as we go deeper in json structure, how to store some values along the node path, so that we can use this variables to update some part of structure while keeping the rest untouched?

EDIT: The example above was incorrect because it can be easily solved without using `capture` function I was asking about. I will present another example. The problem is, that I don't know how to use `|=` to update part of json, if `capture` returns `json-data` where I will lose the data needed for the update, not understanding sufficiently, why declaring variable blocks me from using `|=` sometimes  etc etc. Ie. I have no idea how to use it, despite of many attempts and googling.

```
{
  "arr": [
    {
      "a": {
        "id": "a100",
        "b": {
          "c": [
            {
              "data": [
                {
                  "something": null
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "a": {
        "id": "bPleaseUseRegex100",
        "b": {
          "c": [
            {
              "data": [
                {
                  "something": null
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

to produce:

```
{
  "arr": [
    {
      "a": {
        "id": "a100",
        "b": {
          "c": [
            {
              "data": [
                {
                  "something": "a100a"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "a": {
        "id": "bPleaseUseRegex100",
        "b": {
          "c": [
            {
              "data": [
                {
                  "something": "bPleaseUseRegex100bPleaseUseRegex"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

about regex rule: everything from start of `id` until first decimal has to be  appended to the `id` to produce `something`. Tbh I don't care if you use `.*` instead, just please use `capture` function to see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually not too far off, except

1. You want to use `map` so that the final result stays an array.
2. You want to use a `|=` instead of an `=` to alter a subpath of `.` while still returning `.`.
3. You don't actually need a regex to grab two characters off of the beginning of a string.

So this ought to work:

```
jq 'map((.id + .id[0:2]) as $newid | .data[].something |= $newid)`
```

Comment: does it reflect our assumption, that top-level array is just a simplification for example brewity? If the array would be well-nested in json, this `map` thing wouldn't work, would it? — I have harder input json to work with, but I tried to simplify it down for stackoverflow, this was the best I was able to come up with, therefore the "assumption" paragraph. Maybe wrong example, sorry.

Comment: @MartinMucha it would work except you would do `.path.to.the.array |= map( ... )`

Comment: OK, it was definitely a bad example, I similified it too much I believe. This is learning question, and I'd like to know, how to use capture function, despite if this oversimplified example can be solved without it. Even with your help, even if I'd rip my head off, I cannot figure out how to use it, when data to capture is on `.path.to.the.array`. I will update the question with better example json.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for @hobbs, who provided a lot help to solve this.

regarding the updated question, which asked about using capture, the solution looks like this:

```
jq '.arr |= map(.a.id as $id | .a.b.c[].data[].something |= ($id | capture("(?<a>[a-zA-z]*)(?<b>.*)") | (.a+.b+.a)  ) ) ' < a.json > c.json
```

so what I was missing, and what was required to move from hobbs answer to using `capture` function was just a pair or `()`. Let me try to explain this(I'm nowhere near hobbs knowledge, but lets try).

you identify array you want to update, in this case `.arr`. You have to update it, otherwise you won't get original data in result. You update `arr` array using `map`, which  in this case applies some transformation and return new array; in this example there are just 2 things: variable assignment, which does not change context, and another `|=` operator, so the first `|=` updates `.arr` with updated self. About transformation within `map`: first we declare `$id` variable, which does not change the context. Then we say, that within current context, we would like to update `.a.b.c[].data[].something` with new value. That new value can be literal, or something, which does not change context, and since capture does that, we just need to use brackets `()`. So here within brackets we expand variable `$id`, capture regex, and from new context produced by `capture`, we produce new value for `something` using string concatenation `(.a+.b+.a)`.

(disclaimer: I'm jq learner, so some terminology in explanation might be shaky, but provided command should work)